# How can one conditionally delete rows in bulk

Tags: if-statement, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to delete rows in bulk which has values as web links starting with "www."
There are 1000+ such entries in my Google Spreadsheet which starts with "https://www." and "www."

I wish to delete only those starting with "www." and I tried this code in GAS.I'm pretty naive to GAS.
Unfortunately I'm missing out on some part of code due to which it is deleting all instances which has "www."

Below I have pasted the code snippet:

```
function deleteRows() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var rows = sheet.getDataRange();
  var numRows = rows.getNumRows();
  var values = rows.getValues();
  var toDelete = [];
  var re = new RegExp('www.'); 

  for (var row = 0; row < values.length; row++) { 
    for(var column = 0;column<values[row].length;column++){ 
      if (re.exec(values[row][column])){
        toDelete.push(row); 
      } 
    } 
  }

  for(var deleteRow = toDelete.length-1; deleteRow >= 0;deleteRow--){
    sheet.deleteRow(toDelete[deleteRow]+1);
  }
```

Also I did try out this which worked partially after tweaking.
[Delete row in Google Sheets if certain "word" is found in cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36116050/delete-row-in-google-sheets-if-certain-word-is-found-in-cell)

Comment: So your problem is that it deletes any row with a cell which contains www. anywhere? Try changing the regex to `"^www\."`

Comment: @RobinGertenbach Let me give it a try.

Comment: That worked. Thanks RobinGertenbach. I have also implemented in same code removal of duplicates and UI for user input.Quick guidance is much appreciated.